# How can i apply woff fonts in Azure for .NEt core app?

Tags: c#, azure, fonts

I ahve a .Net Core MVC app that uses DinkToPdf, which wraps libwkhtmltox.dll, to create PDF files from HTML. One of the fonts i am using is a .woff font and this works fine on my local machine. However in Azure, the font is not applied.

I have read other threads that state the mimeTypes should be added to FileExtensionContentTypeProvider ofr .Net Core as opposed to the web.config in .Net apps.

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        provider.Mappings[".woff"] = "font/woff";
        provider.Mappings[".ttf"] = "font/ttf";
        provider.Mappings[".otf"] = "font/otf";
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "fonts")),
            RequestPath = "/fonts",
            ContentTypeProvider = provider
        });
```

I have also tried the different mimeTypes, but believ these are the correct ones. You can see i ahve also added .ttf and .otf to see if Azure had a problem with one and not the other. I am then referenceing the font in css as per below...

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'barcode';
src: url(../fonts/fre3of9x.woff) format('woff'), url(../fonts/fre3of9x.ttf) format('ttf'), url(../fonts/CODE39.otf) format('otf');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

I can't see anything in Azure that i can set so i have hit a brick wall. Can anyone help?

Comment: I dont know if this will fix your issue, but try right clicking on the woff files in solution explorer -> properties -> Copy to Output Directory, set to 'Copy Always'. The file is probably missing from azure. How are you deploying your app?

Comment: I can see the files in azure under the font folder which comes under the wwwroot folder. The deployment automatically includes everything in this directory i belive.

Comment: Could the path be incorrect on Azure? in your css you have `../fonts/`, try without the `../`

Comment: Yes, and then it doesn't even display the text.

Answer (score 2):

Azure App Service, which I assume you are using, is basically just IIS. IIS doesn't have support for WOFF out of the box. This will require you to add a web.config to the root of your project and make sure that it gets deployed to the App Service. Here is what will need to be in the web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/font-woff" /> 
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.

You may have to explicitly remove the extensions and add them back. This is the one I use in a few websites that I know works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/font-woff" />
  </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: As this is .Net Core, the web config is a json file and is a little different. I'm not sure if it handles the same content? Do you know?

Comment: Ah, i didn't realise that a web.config file is actually deployed to Azure even though not use locally. But i ahve added the staticContent section and still doesn't apply the font.

Comment: That is interseting,  have you restarted the App Service. As far as the web.config, you even have to use one for Python projects if you want the same behavior. End in the end unless you are using the Linux/Container hosting App Service it's still IIS.

Comment: Changing the web.config restarts the application, so yes i have tried this. Again i have tried different mime types as some articles have application/font-woff and some have font/woff, but to no avail.  so now the web.config has...<staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="font/ttf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: Is your web.config at the root?

Comment: Yes the web.config is at the root.

Comment: I have tried all suggestions and other articles all refer to the same as what you have suggested above so a little stuck now. There must be a solution.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the filesystem on the App Service? You can do that through the console and then just type ls

Comment: App_Offline.htm
DinkToPdf.dll
Dsm.PrecompiledViews.dll
Dsm.PrecompiledViews.pdb
Dsm.deps.json
Dsm.dll
Dsm.pdb
Dsm.runtimeconfig.json
SendGrid.dll
ZetPDF.dll
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.json
appsettings.production.json
bundleconfig.json
hostingstart.html
libwkhtmltox.dll
web.config
wwwroot

Comment: in the wwwroot folder is... css
favicon.ico
fonts
images
js
lib

Comment: So this appears to be a font issue on the PDF, as it can be applied to text on the website. But still the strange things is that it works locally and not in Azure.

Comment: are you deploying the web.config? If yes, then try to not deploy it. The web.config should be generated automatically. Then, go to Kudu (Portal / Web App / Advanced Tools / Console), and manually edit the web.config with those lines